# why PhotoRec recovery file name does not match the name of the initial file?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I used Photorec to recover files from an internal hard drive which I connected externally to another PC. With PhotoRec all the file names are wrong .

What the solution?

Comment: See this related answer for a solution: http://superuser.com/a/1144489/278831

Answer (score 1):

Photorec doesn't read the original filesystem, so it doesn't see what the original filename was.

It just reads all the data on the drive, copying out files "magically" when it sees one (you'd have to delve into it's [website](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) &/or source code to see exactly how it works, it's close enough to "magic" for me ;-)

The only solutions are to:

- rename the files yourself, using their contents as a guide (easy for MP3's, not so easy for others), or
- use a different tool to recover the files, maybe [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) (by the same author), that's *only if* the filesystem is somewhat intact.