# check disk interrupted, all data is now inaccessible, any way to recover it?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, data-recovery

I have a 5TB external NTFS drive thats nearly full. It was exhibiting an odd behavior: I would copy a file to it, the total space free would adjust accordingly, but the file was nowhere to be found.

So I ran check disk on it (from the Windows 7 UI, not the command line) on it and the check disk seemed to get stuck (*The file number that it was working on did not change for over 36 hours*), so I cancelled the check.

Now, the drive is unreadable. It is recognized in device manager, and in `diskmgmt.msc` it is shown as an unallocated drive, and it prompts to me allow disk management to initialize it with MBR or GPT.

So, at least the drive isn't broken. How can I recover the data?

Comment: It might as well be broken, if you intialize the drive your data will be lost, but based on the behavior that happened before the chkdsk happened

Comment: I know initializing will erase, by not broken I mean I could use it again the future for storing other data. Also, what happened `before the chkdisk happened`?

Comment: I wouldn't because if it's unhealthy enough to do this once it will happen again

Comment: See [Recovering broken or deleted NTFS partitions](http://askubuntu.com/a/776317/271) and also [How can I efficiently recover a permanently deleted folder at once?](http://superuser.com/a/1144489/278831).

Answer (score 0):

If your data is important then firstly try not to write anything on it as there could be a chances of overwriting of data. Try anything of your own make take you to complete loss of data. Try to take help of data recovery experts in this case. There are many companies which provides free consultation.Search for them.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)