# sort recovered image files with exif data to existing files

Tags: data-recovery, rename, sorting, exif, digikam

I managed to recover lots of images (canon cr2 + accompanying jpg) from a failing hard-drive with recurva.
It created a lot of files with some sort of hash-filename. So it is a bit complicated to sort the files into their appropriate folders and/or rename them back to their original name.
But all these image files still have valid exif data stored with them. So it is possible to read the correct file creation date and such.

Is there any automated method ready that could help me sort and rename them via that exif data?

Comment: [ExifTool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) and a batch file should be able to do what you want.

Comment: See [How to add missing file extensions for multiple files using ExifTool in Windows](//superuser.com/q/1132133) for inspiration

Comment: I thought of somethine along the line of this (although there might be another way):
    - iterate over existing not lost files 
    - for each file check the creation date
    - iterate over recovered files
    - check if the creation date of the recovered file is older than the "original" -> if so order it after the "original", if it is equal delete the recovered;
I hope there is already a tool available doing this, otherwise I'll head over to main-stack to ask how to program something myself.

Comment: Not really what you are looking for, but... was the drive NTFS? In that case you could have much better luck in recovering the whole directory structure (including file names) with tools like this: [Recovering broken or deleted NTFS partitions](http://askubuntu.com/a/776317/271).

Comment: See also: [How can I efficiently recover a permanently deleted folder at once?](http://superuser.com/a/1144489/278831).

Comment: thanks, no it wasn't ntfs and there wasn't even a file structure yet. Just the file names are different now. I was going to sort them into folders next if they had not been deleted.
But as I'm doing that task (sorting of files by [exif] date) regularly it might be beneficial to have such tool anyways.
I guess I'll look into it myself and use ExifTool + batch like @DavidPostill suggested. :)

Comment: I see. To do that I usually just follow one of these links I bookmarked: https://del.icio.us/TheLazza/exif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the great tool [digikam](https://www.digikam.org/) is able to do this via gui. It has exiv2 included and can use it for batch rename and so much more!

Comment: Well done for finding a solution and posting it! :) I think future readers might like to see some steps and/or a screenshot, though. Could you consider adding those?

Comment: if I find the time and remember to do it, I'll do it :)