# Access Data on Lenovo Laptop HardDrive (Not Password Protected)

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, data-recovery, lenovo-laptop

**Background**:

Lenovo Ideapad Y480 Laptop is not booting to either the hard drive (Samsung HD I believe) or to any Linux Live CD's. The laptop turns off shortly after it starts displaying OS loading screens (whether that's the Win7 loading screen or the Ubuntu Live loading screen). Sometimes the laptop will get all the way to the Windows login before just shutting off.

I've been able to get to the BIOS of the laptop and verify that there is no password protection on the Hard drive.

**Important:** At one point I was able to get the Laptop booted to Win7 (using both power adapter and battery) for a bit and transfer several gigs of pictures off of the hard drive onto a usb drive. At some point I unplugged the laptop so that I could move rooms and continue transferring data. The laptop froze and has exhibited the above behavior since.

**What I'm trying to do**

That said, I'm attempting to get the data (specifically pictures) off the laptops hard drive. I've taken the hard drive out of the laptop, put it in a 2.5" external hard drive enclosure, and connected it via USB 3.0 to my desktop.

There appear to be three partitions on the hard drive. Two Lenovo specific partitions and then the main partition that Win7 and all the files live on. I can access the files on two partitions but I cannot access the files on the Win7 partition. The filesystem it's formatted with is one that Ubuntu (and win10 for that matter) doesn't recognize.

[image: PartitionThereButNotRecognized]

How can I access the data in the win7 partition on this Lenovo laptop Hard Drive?

Comment: Please see this answer, try it and report if it worked for you: http://superuser.com/a/1144489/278831

Comment: Did you manage to try TestDisk and RecuperaBit as suggested in the link above?