# Recovery of windows

Tags: windows, filesystems, data-recovery

Windows does not boot anymore, as shown in the images below the error code `0xc0000185` is displayed. I never did a backup or a recovery disk of Windows, is there anyway to fix this? I assume that that file system was corrupted due to a sudden lack of electricity in the middle of a uninstallation process. What I care most is to recover my data.

I tried to pull out the HDD from the notebook and tried accessing its data from another PC, but it didn't work.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNZjK.jpg]

Translation:

> ## Recovery
>
> ### Can't start the PC correctly
>
> A necessary device is not connected or is inaccessible.
>
> Error code: 0xc0000185
>
> It will be necessary to use the recovery tool provided with the
>   installation medium. If you don't have the installation medium (disc
>   or USB device) get in touch with the system administrator or the PC
>   manufacturer.
>
> - Press Enter to retry
> - Press F8 to show boot options
> - Press ESC to show the UEFI settings

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9EVN.jpg]

Translation:

> ## :(
>
> The computer encountered a problem and must be rebooted. The
>   collection of information about the error is going on. At the end, it
>   will be possible to reboot the computer. (0% completed)
>
> To get more information, search this error online: NTFS_FILE_SYSTEM

Comment: Please translate your error message into English. [edit] and add the translations to the question.

Comment: “tried accessing its data from another PC, but it won't work” Well actually if the system half-boots the NTFS drive is not really broken so that would most likely work. Of course use Linux on the target computer (or directly via live USB) for the recovery, not Windows. See also: https://superuser.com/a/1144489/278831

Comment: @DavidPostill I edited OP's post with a translation. It's currently pending review.

Answer (score 2):

There are many options available to do that :

**A)** If you have the windows installation media, or [a recovery disc](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-create-a-windows-recovery-drive-2625164) (maybe using someone else's PC to make one), you can try doing a system repair.

**B)** You can also try to access [the "advanced startup options" menu](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-access-advanced-startup-options-in-windows-10-or-8-2626229).

**C)** If both of the previous options aren't working, try to go to the "safe mode" menu, by pressing **F8** right after BIOS/UEFI prompt (you can also "spam" the key after power button press). Then, choose **command line** from there, and try to run `chkdsk C: /x` (it's windows' [self repairing utility](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730714(v=ws.11).aspx)).

**D)** Use [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) to recover/rebuild NTFS boot sector and NTFS MFT.

---

Don't hesitate to ask (or edit) if anything here seems unclear.

Comment: Thank you, I'll start with the one, reading the guide you suggested I can't get if I can make a recovery disk from my other PC which run windows10 instead.

Comment: It should be noted that TestDisk *does not* "repair" NTFS partitions.

Comment: @AlessandroSassi no. you'll need another PC running the **same version** of windows

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto corrected

Comment: Sorry to be a bit picky, but... it does not rebuild MFT entries either. :P It can only read the first four from backup (pretty useless on their own), that's it.