# How to recover data on PC?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, data-recovery

I wanted to reinstall the windows, so I have formatted the C: partition and when I tried to install windows it showed me MBR error. Somewhere on internet I have found the solution for that problem, and it was to clean the disk and convert it to GPT before installing the windows. And I did that, but what happened was that it has formatted also my D: disk and made the one disk of those two, so I lost all the data from the D: disk. Now I am afraid to install operating system cause I am scared that it may overwrite my data if there is still any chance to recover it. So is there any chance?

Comment: I've always liked PhotoRec for recovery. It of course is not guaranteed, but has done well for me in the past, even off flash disks that have been formatted: http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec

Comment: @MaQleod you mean TestDisk, I hope...

Comment: See also a write-up on how to use TestDisk and RecuperaBit for NTFS recovery here: https://superuser.com/a/1144489/278831

Answer (score 0):

I don't guarantee that this will recover ALL your files, but you can try the following free tools try recover your deleted partitions:

- [DMDE Free Edition](https://dmde.com/download.html)
- [Paragon Rescue Kit Free Edition](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/rk-free/)  (Useful if you can't boot all into OS)