# Recycle Bin on Windows disappeared

Tags: windows, windows-10, data-recovery, recycle-bin

I accidentally (and stupidly) wrote the following command:

```
rm -r blah ~
```

I meant to write the following:

```
rm -r blah "~"
```

Fortunately I managed to stop it at around ".android" as there was a readonly file there.

Unfortunately the recycle bin folder seems to have disappeared from the Windows file explorer.

How can I get the recycle bin back?

For extra points, any idea how I can recover the deleted data?

**NOTE:** I installed git bash commands, so you can do bash commands on command prompt

Comment: rm isn't a windows command, so can it be safely assumed you were in a bash shell?

Comment: I installed git bash commands, so you can do bash commands on command prompt

Comment: Ok, that may change the answer to your questions, so might be worth clarifying.

Comment: “how I can recover the deleted data?” The usual way, I guess: https://superuser.com/a/1144489/278831

Answer (score 1):

From [Microsoft support site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/15057/windows-show-hide-recycle-bin) :

---

Here's how to get the Recycle Bin on your desktop in Windows 10:

1. Select the Start  button, then select Settings .
2. Select Personalization > Themes > Desktop icon settings.
3. Select the Recycle Bin check box > Apply.

For your deleted data unfortunately what is done is done sorry...