# Lost all files after windows installation became damaged

Tags: windows-10, data-recovery, partition-recovery, hard-drive-recovery, file-recovery

Last week, my laptop hung for a while, I couldn't do anything then it went into automatic repair, then it tells me it was unable to repair the pc. I had to reinstall windows, I found my files in windows.old.  This same issue has just happened today, and I tried to do a new windows installation like last time, but this time, when I got to the windows installation screen where you select the partition type. I noticed my primary 932GB partition was completely unused, but I proceeded with the installation anyway, now installation is complete. All my files are gone! Harddrive is completely free! There's no windows.old. How can I recover these files, please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recover Windows 10 data?](https://superuser.com/questions/1241525/recover-windows-10-data)

Comment: @Moab For my situation, I made a new windows installation on the empty harddrive which I hope it hasn't overwritten it. I think this is not the case for the question you linked me to but I'm about to checkout the puppy linux solution offered in the answers.

Comment: Use the last disk image you made to restore everything.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Could you please elaborate? I installed with a disc. Also note that, the files were already gone before I started the installation (I noticed this on the screen where you select the partition to install windows on)

Comment: @DrMoishe_Pippik ... "Use the last disk image you made to restore everything".. it is my experience that most users don't make backup images.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: You are probably mostly screwed.  Rewriting an entire installation over the top of that partition probably wiped out most of what you have.  I myself suggest [TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download) to recover what you can.  Whatever you do, DONT PUT ANYTHING ELSE ON THAT DRIVE!!  Ideally you want to pull the drive out and run testdisk from another installation/computer.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Thanks. I'll try this out and revert.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I was able get some of the files with recuva. Though, it was difficult and tiring but worth it.

Comment: Awesome! I am glad you got some of your files back! :)

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Thank you!!