# Drive has become unreadable, chkdsk reports: "The type of the file system is RAW."

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, data-recovery

Had an unexpected system shutdown occur at probably the worst possible moment, while a chkdsk /r /f /x operation was underway on a local drive, and now I suspect the boot sector is unreadable, so no partitions are being found on the drive. Physical damage to the drive is not suspected in this instance, and this was not the operating system drive, so the system is bootable.

What would you recommend as the best way to restore the partition or recover the data?

Here's what I'm currently doing (please correct me if any of this is incorrect or unwise)

- Ran [TestDisk 7.0](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/Main_Page) data recovery utility
- Selected option: [Create] log file
- Selected the volume with the missing partition (volumes appeared in the list both using their physical descriptors and their windows-assigned drive letters, I selected the non-drive-letter option.
- Selected [Intel] as the partition table type
- Selected [Analyze]
- TestDisk reported a partition read error:
  [image]
- TestDisk now appears to be performing a deep scan to figure out what's on the drive:
  [image]

Is this the correct utility to use to try to fix this and the correct way to go about it? Are there any other cautions or recommendations I should consider, or things to expect once the scan is done? (This is a 4TB drive, so I expect it to take a long time.)

(I'm primarily following the instructions listed [here](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step).)

Thank you so much!

Comment: "Is this the correct utility to use to try to fix this and the correct way to go about it?" - Yes

Comment: IMO, if you do anything that writes to the drive prior to making a backup, you are not following a correct procedure -- especially where no physical damage to the drive is suspected. Why in the world would you do anything irreversible that might cause data loss when you are under no pressure whatsoever?!

Comment: If TestDisk cannot open the partition, it is broken and you should use RecuperaBit. See the last part of this answer as well: https://superuser.com/a/1144489/278831