# EaseUS Data Recovery works!...But cannot recover files after scanned

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, ntfs, raw

so I used EaseUS Data Recovery Tool Wizard as it was the only application that could successfully read my hard-drive.

My external hard-drive fell from the table and since then it's converted from an NTFS to a RAW drive. When I plug it in, the computer recognises it but cannot open it as I get an "Incorrect Function" error. Applications like Disk Management can read it too, however it takes a very long time to load, since the HDD takes so long to read.

EaseUS Data Recovery Tool took about 8~ hours to read the disk, but was able to find all 600GB+ of data. I can preview images, text documents and music if I double click them (takes awhile), but when I try to recover the data, it hangs on 'Recovering File' and does not work, no % was made after 10+ hours. This was attempted again with recovering one image, no % was made after 10+ hours again.

Any alternatives to my situation? Is there other applications that I could try? Or is there something up with my EaseUS application?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! *First* you should make a clone of the whole drive, after you can work on recovery. See this answer as well: https://superuser.com/a/1144489/278831

Comment: Did you make sure there is no popup dialog or anything that informs you that you need to obtain a license for that operation to work? Do you have a license for that software?

Comment: Yeah, I own the program. Seems like the best course of action is to clone the hard-drive entirely through DDRescue on Linux and then re-try the recovery on that cloned drive.