# Recovering files on Linux through a directory structure

Tags: linux, windows, data-recovery

Like an idiot, I didn't have a backup of my hardrive, and Windows attempted to update several times but failed because, after running a scan, my hard drive is failing. On one of the update attempts, my computer died. After logging in, I was greeted with the Windows temporary account, and all my files were still there, but heading the warnings, I tried to fix the issue rather than backing up the data immediately, which didn't work, and after trying a few times, I checked my user folder to begin a backup, and everything was gone.

My friend and I booted the computer onto a live Linux USB, and took an image of the drive, and began restoring files with TestDisk, which restored thousands of files, only to realize, they were all restored under UUID#### folders in the root directory, but no directory structure was preserved, so I have no idea where to even begin either where to put what. The current theory is that the thumbs.db file, or whatever stores directory structure information was corrupted.

Is there any way, or any program that can restore files into a directory structure so I don't have to painstakingly sort through every file?

Comment: You could start by telling us which file system (or file systems, if there were several partitions) you have on the faulty harddrive (NTFS? ext4? FAT? Something else?). The answer depends *a lot* on the type of filesystem.

Comment: NTFS, and on the image we took with DD, every partiton was included.

Comment: Thumbs.db has absolutely nothing to do with the directory structure.

Comment: Also, please read this answer (especially the last part): https://superuser.com/a/1144489/278831 and this one: https://askubuntu.com/a/776317/271