# Recovering data from Dead Hard disk

Tags: hard-drive, boot, data-recovery, hard-drive-recovery, partition-recovery

My laptop is dual booted with Ubuntu 14 and Windows 10. When I booted up my System there was beep sound at the BIOS screen, taking to the service person said that the hard disk (Seagate 500GB) is dead. The recovery and the service charge was extremely expensive. So I had to look for an alternate way.

I used [this EaseUs tool](https://www.easeus.com/data-recovery-wizard-winpe/) to make a bootable windows on my USB Pen drive and saw that I can see my Hard disk but it shows empty (500GB free). I was relieved slightly by assuring that it was not a Hardware issue.

My question is how to :

1. Restore the OS and partitions as it was before.
2. Recover files and folder structure from both the OS partition..
3. If it is a problem with MBR, how to repair/fix it?
4. I have also purchased [SATA to USB3.0 Converter](https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B078K9GDTG/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) so I could use some tools to use my hard drive as slave and recover data.

Please suggest me a way or a tool which would help me get the data back.

Thanks.

Comment: Your multiple questions boil down to recovery software and software recommendations are off topic here. Also using such software is not always easy and results vary a lot. If you have valuable personal data you absolutely need to recover that's your last chance. Otherwise don't even bother. OS and software can be reinstalled.

Comment: @MichaelBay May i know how I could recover my data

Comment: See also https://superuser.com/q/1270603/278831