# Data Recovery on a Repartitioned SSD

Tags: ssd, data-recovery, trim

Is data recovery possible from an SSD where the partitions were deleted, and new partitions were created, then formatted?  The file system is NTFS.

I understand data recovery is generally not possible on SSDs with TRIM when files are deleted, but I'm not sure if TRIM applies to deleted partitions.  Also, it was deleted in the Preinstallation Environment, and I'm not sure if TRIM functions there.

Comment: What file recovery/partition recovery software have you tried?  Have you even tried?  This a practical question or a “is it possible” question?

Comment: @Ramhound I tried Recuva, but you have to select a volume, not a physical drive, so it didn't work.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm currently trying to learn Autopsy, but it doesn't list the file extension I'm looking for, and the search feature can't search for specific extentions...

Comment: Here's an answer of mine that should help you: https://superuser.com/a/1144489/278831

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto Thanks, good information, but pertains to deleted files, not deleted partitions.  Funny how these sorts of questions get modded down and the answers modded up...

Comment: @Jason the linked answer absolutely pertains to deleted partitions.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto Really? It doesn't even mention partitions.

Comment: @DavidPostill yes. RecuperaBit can rebuild broken, deleted and partially overwritten NTFS partitions. Actually also some other tools but I didn't mention  them in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you only did quick format of the partitions, recovery might be possible
by using a product that scans the disk.
Deleting a partition only changes the partition table and does not TRIM
the partition data.

The disk tables are not of much help, since someone did a good job of
destroying them, so the recovery of files whose sectors are not contiguous
on the disk is doubtful or only partially possible.

Some recovery products you may try are :
[Recuva](https://www.piriform.com/recuva),
[TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk),
[PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec).

Comment: "only partially possible" Definitely partially possible, but not with those tools listed there (which are great but for slightly different scenarios).

Comment: Testdisk does not do any kind of MFT reconstruction. Neither does Recuva. Photorec is a file carver. None of them will work if parts of the MFT are broken or if the partition boundaries are not clearly defined.

Comment: When it comes to damaged MFTs, there are several tools that work better than the aforementioned ones. Examples include DMDE, Restorer Ultimate Pro and GetDataBack. I use Testdisk and Photorec quite often. They are great but they do *different* things which save the day in different scenarios, just not with damaged MFTs. I know what they do and **how** they do it. Again, they are great but for slightly different purposes.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of formatting:
Quick formatting and full formatting. If you have done quick formatting then you can recover your data back, but if you have full formatting of data then the chances of recovery are very less.
Quick-format helps you remove/delete data from the hard drive. When you quick format a hard drive, only the file pointers get deleted, and the drive space becomes available for new data storage. However, data becomes inaccessible but remains available.
There are various data recovery software that can help you to recover data from deleted partitions, you can try that.