# Recover data from hard disk partition

Tags: data-recovery

I have a 190 GB NTFS partition which I can't access. When I tried opening it on Ubuntu, I got an error saying "Failed to load $MFT: No such file or directory."

Chkdsk on Windows also failed to recover MFT.

However the data recovery software show me that the files are still present and in "excellent" condition and are recoverable but I know it will take a long time to recover that much data considering it's an old HDD.

Is there a way to recover/fix the MFT so that the partition can be accessed normally from Windows?

Hope you understand my question. English isn't my main language.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: First image the disk, before further corruption occurs. Then you might try third-party tools, such as https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/Advanced_NTFS_Boot_and_MFT_Repair and http://www.ntfs.com/recovery-toolkit.htm .

Comment: In-place recovery always can cause additional data damage. So the first step is to make its copy (or image at least). But I recommend to recover the files to another HDD using any euristic recovery tool (they never use in-place recover, moreover, they never write to the volume recovered) and check them - "excellent" prognosis does not mean correct recovery (from practice!).

Comment: See this answer of mine that also works for broken NTFS: https://superuser.com/a/1144489/278831 (and no, you don't want to mess with the FS in-place)