# folder for no reason converts into file - why? where is my data now? can I get it back?

Tags: linux, filesystems, data-recovery, ntfs, ext4

I just shut down my PC yesterday and when I started it today the directory, where I saved my important files is not there anymore and instead there is a file with the following content:

```
"AppWorkshop"
{
    "appid"     "346110"
    "SizeOnDisk"        "80910366"
    "NeedsUpdate"       "0"
    "NeedsDownload"     "0"
    "TimeLastUpdated"       "1535910993"
    "TimeLastAppRan"        "0"
    "WorkshopItemsInstalled"
    {
        "895711211"
        {
            "size"      "80910366"
            "timeupdated"       "1530808198"
            "manifest"      "3309829551782067496"
        }
    }
    "WorkshopItemDetails"
    {
        "895711211"
        {
            "manifest"      "3309829551782067496"
            "timeupdated"       "1530808198"
            "timetouched"       "0"
            "subscribedby"      "126337562"
        }
    }
}
```

- What does this mean?
- Can I get my data back somehow?
- What happened to it, how can this happen?
- Has anybody had the same problem?

---

I am running Antergos (Arch Linux) with KDE Plasma 5 on an i7 7700K, a GTX 970, 16GB DDR4 RAM.

The Directory was on a NTFS partition (not using Windows) and I created a link to it in my home directory and accessed the files through that link. Yesterday I was able to copy files there and save my blender project.

Comment: `AppWorkshop` and an _appid_ of [`346110`](https://steamdb.info/app/346110/) both point to Steam and "[_ARK:Survival Evolved_](https://store.steampowered.com/app/346110/ARK_Survival_Evolved/)"... did you download or update the game?

Comment: oh, ok I had something like steam in my mind, but it was just running in the background and I was not installing ark.

but now, that I think about it thats also wierd, but more reasonable: I started windows that evening and it may have messed with the files.

Comment: You might want to give RecuperaBit a try: https://superuser.com/a/1144489/278831 (I am the author)